# What is the concurrent requests limit for Google BigQuery streaming insert?

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the concurrent requests limit for Google BigQuery streaming insert?

I found that there is a limit for BigQuery API but it does not apply for streaming insert.

> **Concurrent API requests, per user: 300**
>
> If you make more than 300 concurrent requests per user, throttling
>   might occur. This limit does not apply to streaming inserts.

Answer (score 3):

Below is available at [Streaming Inserts Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts)

> The following limits apply for streaming data into BigQuery.
>
> - **Maximum row size**: 1 MB. Exceeding this value will cause invalid errors.
> - **HTTP request size limit**: 10 MB. Exceeding this value will cause invalid errors.
> - **Maximum rows per second**: 100,000 rows per second, per project. Exceeding this amount will cause quotaExceeded errors. The maximum number of rows per second per table is also 100,000.
>     You can use all of this quota on one table or you can divide this quota among several tables in a project.
> - **Maximum rows per request**: 10,000 rows per request. We recommend a maximum of 500 rows.
>     Batching can increase performance and throughput to a point, but at the cost of per-request latency. Too few rows per request and the overhead of each request can make ingestion inefficient. Too many rows per request and the throughput may drop.
> - **Maximum bytes per second**: 100 MB per second, per table. Exceeding this amount will cause quotaExceeded errors.

I think, collectivelly, above sets some sort of concurrency limits

Comment: not really if Google has a separate concurrency limit for streaming insert. I saw a separate concurrency limit for other API requests. If the case is as you said, they should explicitly mention it in there documentation. I'm still waiting for a confirmation from Google.

Comment: Check the link for the real limits, since things have changed. Maximum rows per second: 1,000,000, for example.