# Google Pub/Sub + Cloud Run scalability

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I have a python application writing pubsub msg into Bigquery. The python code use the google-cloud-bigquery library and the `TableData.insertAll()` method quota is 10,000 requests per second per table.Q[uotas documentation](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#streaminginserts).

Cloud Run container auto scaling is set to 100 with 1000 requests per container.So technically, I should be able to reach 10 000 requests/sec right? With the BQ insert API being the biggest bottleneck.

I only have a few 100 requests per sec at the moment, with multiple service running at the same time.

CPU and RAM at 50%.

Comment: 100 requests per secong? to bigquery or to Cloud Run? If it's BigQuery, how long take a request to be processed? more or less than 1s? unary, and with multiple concurrent request also.

Comment: 500-600 requests/sec to Bigquery. The request takes 5 sec to process.

Comment: What are your machine parameters? Memory/CPU count? I've achieved nice scalability with Cloud Run and BigQuery without using pub/sub. How do you catch duplicate pub/sub messages?

Comment: If each Cloud Run instance have default configuration (1 vCPU) that's fine!

Comment: 2 vCore and 256Mb of RAM. Does it mean that I can increase the requests rate if I add more CPU or RAM?

Comment: You'll have to try and see what your utilization is to optimize those parameters. What is your architecture? Cloud Run --> Pub/Sub --> BigQuery? Or Pub/Sub --> Cloud Run --> BigQuery?

Comment: Pub/Sub --> Cloud Run --> BigQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now confirming your project structure, and a few details given in the comments; I would then review the [Pub/Sub quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas), especially the  Quota and the Resource limits, both tables where you can check this information depending on the size and the Throughput quota units sections tells you how to calculate quota usage.

I would answer your question as a yes, you are able to reach 10,000 req/sec. And as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330968/what-is-the-concurrent-requests-limit-for-google-bigquery-streaming-insert) depending on the byte size you can have 10,000 row inserts unless the recommendation is 500.

The [concurrency](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency) in Cloud Run can be modified in case you need to change it.

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can click on the checkmark icon to mark it as accepted. This can help future users who are having the same issue.